# Laravel 5: force to validate [GET] requests using csrf

Tags: php, security, laravel, laravel-5, csrf

by default Laravel 5 validate & match "tokens" for all [POST] requests, how to tell L5 to validate "GET, PUT & Delete" requests too?

-> prevent any request without valid token

thanks,

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Laravel validate the token for POST, PUT and DELETE. You don't need to validate the token for a GET request if you follow a RESTful system.

From the documentation:

> You do not need to manually verify the CSRF token on POST, PUT, or DELETE requests. The VerifyCsrfToken HTTP middleware will verify token in the request input matches the token stored in the session.

http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/routing#csrf-protection

Comment: What do you want to validate?

Comment: I want to prevent any request without valid token

Comment: You can set a token on your HTML's meta tags and set in your route's file that you want the `csrf` middleware for a route.

Or, to prevent any request you can modify the `VerifyCsrfToken.php` file to also verify GET request by overiding `isReading()` function.

Comment: do u know how to modify `isReading()` to validate [GET] requests?

Comment: If you want to validate every request you can only return false. Or, remove an item from the array. (https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.1/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/VerifyCsrfToken.php#L117)

Answer (score 4):

You can create your own middleware that will take care of it and replace the default Laravel VerifyCsrfToken class. In Laravel 5.3:

1. Create your new middleware `php artisan make:middleware VerifyCsrfTokenAll`
2. Replace the middleware class in `app/Http/Kernel.php` - search for `protected $middlewareGroups` and replace `VerifyCsrfToken::class` by your new middleware. So it can look like this:

   ```
   protected $middlewareGroups = [
       'web' => [
           \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
           \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
           \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
           \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
           \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfTokenAll::class,
           \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
       ],
       ...
   ```
3. In `app/Http/Middleware/VerifyCsrfTokenAll.php` make it extend original verifier and just override the `isReading()` method as this one is responsible for bypassing the GET requests. Something like this depending on your use case:

   ```
   <?php
   namespace App\Http\Middleware;

   use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken as BaseVerifier;

   class VerifyCsrfTokenAll extends BaseVerifier
   {
       /**
        * Determine if the HTTP request uses a ‘read’ verb.
        *
        * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
        * @return bool
        */
       protected function isReading($request)
       {
           return false;
           // return in_array($request->method(), ['HEAD', 'GET', 'OPTIONS']);
       }

   }
   ```

If you only wanted to validate in on certain routes, it is better to do it as a route middleware as in my case - I created a `VerifyCsrfTokenGet` middleware and assigned it in `app/Http/Kernel` to `$routeMiddleware` group like this:

```
protected $routeMiddleware = [
    'csrf_get' => \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfTokenGet::class,
    ...
```

In `app/Http/MIddleware/VerifyCsrfTokenGet.php` I did the verification:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    // check matching token from GET
    $sessionToken = $request->session()->token();
    $token = $request->input('_token');
    if (! is_string($sessionToken) || ! is_string($token) || !hash_equals($sessionToken, $token) ) {
        throw new \Exception('CSRF token mismatch exception');
    }

    return $next($request);
}
```

and finally assigned this to any route as a `csrf_middleware` whereever I want to validate it, eg. in constructor of some of the controllers:

```
class InvoicesController extends Controller
{
    function __construct()
    {
        // define middleware
        $this->middleware('csrf_get', ['only' => ['pay', 'createmail']]);
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

"csrf token" is just an ordinary session value with a key name "_token" ，you can just get and reset this value directly.
like this：

```
$token = $this->request->get('_token');
if(is_null($token) || $token!=csrf_token())
    throw new AppException('illegal_pay_operation');
else
    Session::regenerateToken();
```