# Turn on CSRF protection for a group of GET routes in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, csrf, middleware, csrf-token

I have the following group of `GET` routes on Laravel:

```
Route::get('/location/get', 'Ajax@getProducts');
Route::get('/products/get', 'Ajax@getProducts');
Route::get('/schedule/get', 'Ajax@getProducts');
```

I want to protect those routes with the automatically generated `CSRF` token from `Laravel`.

I have read some workarounds about overriding method: `VerifyCsrfToken@isReading(...)`, but I'm not too much convinced about that.

Then I'm looking for a more elegant solution.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CSRF is not protecting your data. More info: https://security.stackexchange.com/a/115808

If you has no reason for using GET method with CSRF, just use POST with default `csrf` middleware group:

```php
Route::group(['before' => 'csrf'], function() {
    // your ::post routes
});
```

Anyway, you can try to create VerifyCsrfTokenAll middleware, and use `csrf_get` key from this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41656322/2453148
and then wrap your routes in this group:

```php
Route::group(['before' => 'csrf_get'], function() {
    // your routes
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Best thing I would adhere to is including the @csrf with your blade form.

```
 <form action=“{{ your route name }}” method=“GET”> @csrf </form>
```